# SQLSTATE[HY000] errors

Tags: error

Sometimes my clients site is down and it shows one of the following errors (black text on white screen):

```
[error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::fetchAll() fout: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_135b_0.MYI' 

CDbCommand faalde tijdens het uitvoeren van volgend SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'krycer_be_craft.t' doesn't exist
```

They are the same errors that are shown in the log files (with a bunch of other stuff).
The wierd thing is, it doesn't happen all the time. Nothing changed on the site scince a few weeks also. A few weeks ago I restored a database back-up, but everything worked fine untill now.

Does anyone has an idea? I updated to the latest version and cleared the cache, maybe it'll help but I would like to know the reason behind these errors.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, MySQL has ran out of disk space on the volume that it's trying to write to.  Either that, or your host applies some artificial limit to the size of your MySQL databases that you're bumping up against.